# How to access MouseEvent getX()/getY() from JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, actionlistener, jpopupmenu

I have a popupmenu like this

```
final JPopupMenu contextMenu = new JPopupMenu();
final JMenuItem addTask = new JMenuItem("Add Task");
```

Then i add a MouseListener:

```
component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {    
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                contextMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
}
```

In my Actionlistener for the MenuItem i would like to access the x/y-data from my MouseEvent. Is this possible without saving them in an extra variable? i would like to get something like this:

```
addTask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //System.out.println(Mouse.getX()+", "+Mouse.getY());
        }

    });
```

Comment: _"without saving them in an extra variable?"_ - Is it that big of a problem, one `Point currentPoint` member?

Comment: No, it's not a problem. I just thought if a solution without this would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the mouse coordinate of event which has trggered the popup menu - no it's impossible without to save it. If you want to get the mouse event whcih has triggered the menu item action - yes it's possible: `EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();` will return the event (you should check whether this event is a mouse event and if yes - cast it, because the action can also be triggered with key event).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  AWTEvent evt = EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();
  if (evt instanceof MouseEvent) {
    MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) evt;
  }
}
```